# Handlebars Bindings with Variable

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

i'm trying to create a Binding in Handlebars/Ember to an Object with a dynamic Key like this:

```
{{view Ember.TextArea valueBinding="foo.[view.content.someid]"}}
```

when im trying this with a static Key, everything is working fine

```
{{view Ember.TextArea valueBinding="foo.[bar]"}}
```

i guess that the "view.content.someid" in my Example is treated as a String. Has anybody a hint how I could solve this, or could tell me why this isn't working??

Comment: Try this {{view Ember.TextArea keyBinding="view.content.someid" valueBinding="foo.[key]"}}